# DiscordJS Slash Command Permission Set Error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a problem with the command.permission.set() function for slash commands in discordJS. DiscordJS version is 13. Node Version: v16.8.0.

(I have made a Slash Command Handler in a directory named commands. There are all the files for the commands)

The Error is:

```
TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied permissions is not an Array of ApplicationCommandPermissionData.
```

The code of the Permission Set:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (msg) => {


if (msg.content.startsWith('$')) {
if (msg.content === '$add') {
  const slashCommandData = {};

  const commandFiles = fs
    .readdirSync('./src/commands')
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

  for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require('./commands/' + file);

    console.log("- " + command.data.name);

    slashCommandData['name'] = command.data.name;
    slashCommandData['description'] = command.data.description;

    if (command.data.options !== undefined) {
      console.log('Option for ' + command.data.name);

      slashCommandData['options'] = command.data.options;
    } else {
      slashCommandData['options'] = [];
    }

    
    await client.guilds.cache
    .get('877098630299934740')
    ?.commands.create(slashCommandData);
    
    if (command.data.permission !== undefined) {
      
      console.log("Permission for " + command.data.name);

      const permission = [
        {
            id: '461976441110921218',
            type: 'USER',
            permission: true,
        },
    ]

      const commando = await client.guilds.cache.get('877098630299934740')?.commands.fetch('884318697794195486');
      
      try {

        await commando.permissions.set({ permission })
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      
      }
    }
      }


      msg.reply('Aggiunti i comandi nuovi!');
    }
  }

    });
```

Where I failed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the [`ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager) property of `ApplicationCommands` then you may add a permission using [`ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager#add`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager?scrollTo=add) method.

Here is an example!

```js
    client.guilds.cache.get('877098630299934740').commands.permissions.add({
            command: '884318697794195486',
            permissions: [{
                id: '461976441110921218',
                type: 'USER',
                permission: true,
            }, ]
        })
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
```